# Which switch supports 2 different input voltages and can switch between the 2 when outputting to a single device

Tags: switches, toggle-switch

I have a small heater that runs on a maximum 12v. I am using a PC PSU to power it. I want to know if there is a switch that will allow me to input 12v and 5v from the PSU and in one position of the switch it will output 12v to the heater and in the other position it will output 5v.

What's the name of this switch and how would I wire it to my heater?

Answer (score 0):

> *What's the name of this switch and how would I wire it to my heater?*

It's called an SPDT switch (single pole double throw): -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.moujenglobal.com/post/what-does-spst-spdt-dpst-and-dpdt-mean).

[image]

Make sure you buy a "break before make" SPDT with the appropriate current rating.

Comment: "Break before make" is also known as "non-shorting" and in the absence of a DC current rating, the AC current rating is not an acceptable substitute.